# How can I inquire about an internship at a company that doesn't offer them in my area?

Tags: internship, applications, canada

I'm looking into applying for a software engineering internship at [Intuit Canada](http://www.intuit.ca/intuit-products/index.jsp), but upon visiting the company's career page I've found that they do not offer Canadian internships (with my next best bet being America). I'd prefer not to move for a job so I was planning on contacting the company to inquire about my current predicament.

**How exactly should I go about contacting them? I don't want to come off as too forward, seeing as it's a large company and there's probably some underlying reason why they haven't yet offered the position.**

Also I'm not entirely sure if I should phone them or send an email. But with both of these options how would I go about finding the proper contact information. All I've been able to find on their website are customer service and technical support numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is specific to your situation, so not putting it in an answer. I went to another school in Ontario, and I actually interviewed for a year-long internship position last year. I was very unimpressed by Intuit as software dev. interviewers, but if you're absolutely dead set on Intuit, maybe check if they have listings on your school job board? Or even contact them directly asking about it if you're open/able to take on a year-long internship, because (as of last year, anyway), they definitely exist.

Comment: @Grace Hm, thank you very much for sharing. If it's not too much trouble would you mind getting in touch with me via email (warnicpj@mcmaster.ca) to discuss what exactly you were unimpressed with at Intuit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Research the company and specific area in which you want an internship, so you deeply understand who the people are, how the organization works, and what the business's goals and obstacles are.

Next, put together a specific plan for the internship you envision: what you'd accomplish, how long it would take, the resources you'd need, etc. Approach this from the point of view of the business unit and its leadership - show what's in it for them.

If you can't find a personal referral, try to find a live presentation being given by a leader in that group and meet afterwards for a handshake with a 20-second pitch, asking if you can share it with them at another time. Your goal is simply to get an opportunity in the future to share your idea. Get a card and follow-up as promised.

If you can't find a live presentation, try a similar approach via social media posts by the business unit's leadership, or other members of the team. Linkedin and Twitter are great, but individual Facebook accounts are probably too personal.

Last resort, try a succinct, well-written cover letter, attached to a summary of your proposed internship. Emphasize that you're not seeking payment (your compensation is learning and relationships) and that you're very flexible and would adjust your proposal however they wish.

Then, follow-up with a telephone call at 7:30 in the morning (before an assistant is there to screen your call). If no one answers, try again in 10 minutes, etc.

Make sure you're ready when they answer - friendly, succinct and enthusiastic to help!

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for taking the time to discuss an old question. I managed to get in touch with the company via public events and I've managed to get all the information I need.

Comment: Very aggressive plan. It may work. +1 For the aggressiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you're specifically looking at Intuit for an internship? There are many other large, well-known organizations (especially banks) that offer internships for software engineers, and they have well established programs that can help you develop your talents in a supportive environment.

With that said, if you're wanting to get a timely answer, I would phone them directly and ask to be directed to HR or a hiring manager. From there you can ask about available positions and if they have any internships available. If they don't have an internship program now, they might consider it in the near future.

Comment: In response to your question about there being a particular reason for applying at Intuit. Yes, I've worked with the software they create and I find the whole company very interesting. I've also heard from a number of people that their intern program (in America) is excellent. Also I plan on keeping my options open, so I will probably be apply to some of the internship for banks in my area as well. Thank you for your response though, it will help.