# Is it wise to contact a recruiter over LinkedIn?

Tags: recruitment, internship, linkedin

*Note: This topic stems off [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52345/how-can-i-inquire-about-an-internship-at-a-company-that-doesnt-offer-them-in-my) previously asked question. In which I've attempted to contact Intuit's human resources without any success.*

In summary I'm attempting to contact Intuit Canada to discuss a possible summer internship but I've be unable to find proper contact information to discuss this with someone.

I've managed to find a number of the company's **Talent Acquisition Leader's** on LinkedIn and so far they're the best chance I've had of getting in contact with the company.

Therefore my question is:

**Is it wise to use LinkedIn's "*InMail*" to contact one (or multiple) of these recruiters to discuss my situation or should I look for alternatives to contact the company?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it wise to use LinkedIn's "InMail" to contact one (or multiple) of
>   these recruiters to discuss my situation or should I look for
>   alternatives to contact the company?

Only use LinkedIn if the individual's LinkedIn profile specifically invites such contact.

Otherwise, use the company's formal Careers process.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the company's formal Careers process is not an option in this situation. But upon reviewing some of the recruiters LinkedIn pages I was able to find appropriate contact information.

Answer (score 3):

You have been looking for a while way to contact the company. You have now found a way, but are concerned about using this method.

Set a deadline. If you don't find a better way by the deadline use LinkedIn to contact them.

If you decide not to contact them using LinkedIn and can't find a better way, you will not be able to get the internship. If you do use LinkedIn and offend them, you won't get the internship. But if it works you might get the internship. At some point the best option becomes obvious.